# Maven can not get specific dependencies (stops when downloanding)

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I'm trying to install Maven dependencies using `mvn install` or build project with `mvn clean package`, Maven starts to download files from the central repository, but at some point, downloanding hangs. Here is the output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-
boot-starter-parent/1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-
1.5.9.RELEASE.pom
Progress (1): 7.5 kB
```

and nothing happens next.

In this case, downloading hangs at first dependency, but when I'm creating new Maven project and write `nvm install` some things downloads correctly and suspension takes place later.

I tried to remove all things from `~/.m2` directory, but still the same. No firewall is used.

The environment I working with is Java 9.0.1, Maven 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm a total beginner in Java, not using any IDE, just on terminal to starts a local server with REST API.

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pl.etaxi</groupId>
<artifactId>etaxi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>etaxi</name>
<description>eTaxi Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for Swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JWT tokens -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>--add-modules java.xml.bind</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--add-modules java.xml.bind</argLine>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT: When downgraded to JDK 8 and Maven 3.5.0 suspension takes place later than with JDK 9.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-
boot-starter-parent/1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-
1.5.9.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-
boot-starter-parent/1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-
1.5.9.RELEASE.pom (7.5 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-
boot-dependencies/1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-
1.5.9.RELEASE.pom
Progress (1): 102 kB
```

Does anyone know what can be the reason?

Comment: First I would suggest to use JDK 8 instead of JDK 9  cause your pom states  Java 8...Have you had a previous Maven installed ?

Comment: When I downgraded to JDK 8 and Maven 3.5.0 this first package which hangs on Java 9 is downloaded correctly but hangs later.

Comment: From which Maven version have you downgraded? Have you currently set environment variables like M2_HOME ? Furthermore I would suggest to use JDK 8 first and try to get building your first Maven project...Do you have some kind of proxy configured ? Can you access the given urls in Maven central via `curl` or `wget` on command line ? In particular those which hang?

Comment: I have downgraded from 3.5.2 to 3.5.0. I haven't set M2_HOME env variable personally but in `mvn -v` output it points correctly to maven home directory. No proxy is configured and `wget` has no problems with fetching these Maven central urls. **I've found a not perfect solution for my problem by generating and running a new Maven project created by Spring Initializr. This downloads correctly all problematic dependencies I need in my other project which can be resolved later from `~/m2` directory**. Not perfect, but works and allows me to run API.

Comment: I assume you have some kind of network issue...otherwise that will not happen...